# Cygwin sed: search/replace one single unprintable char using hex, octal or decimal

Tags: sed, cygwin, hex, ascii, octal

sorry for the simple question, but I have gone blind for four days studying and trying, and can't seem to strike the right syntax.

Using sed on cygwin, I am trying to replace one single unprintable ASCII character with another single unprintable character.

Here is my source file, using UPPERCASE text [within square brackets] to denote the unprintable ascii character:

```
myfile.txt:

line one[LF]
line two[LF]
line three[LF]
[SUBSTITUTE][LF]
line four{LF]
line five[LF]
line six[LF]
.
.
.
```

I would like to replace the LFs with TABs.

Since LFs are hex 0A and tabs are hex 09 I have tried, basically, this:

```
sed -i 's/\x0A/\x09/g' myfile.txt
```

which changes nothing in the file.

Of course, I have tried different switches like -b, -e and -r, with brackets and without, with and without the /g, extra backslashes and no backslashes, octal and decimal notation, all the way to Elven runes, with absolutely no success.

I read some answers that used 'echo' instead of a file as the source, they just confused me and didn't work.

Other examples used 'cheats' like the actual word TAB, but they prevented me from learning the syntax using numerics, so I can apply it to other unprintable chars, not just TABs.

When I try the 'file' command, I get:

```
file myfile.txt
file.txt: data
```

So, of course I tried:

```
sed -i -t UTF-8 's/\x0A/\x09/g' myfile.txt
```

but my sed didn't support that -t option.

When I try this:

```
oc -c myfile.txt
```

the [LF] character I'm searching for shows up as :

```
\n
```

I have also tried \0D as my search term, no luck either.

If anyone wants to lend me a clue by showing the correct syntax I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I'm grateful for people trying to help.  If StackOverflow lets me, I will upvote each attempt to help.

I'm answering my own question in hopes it helps someone else.

I learned it's not quite true that sed cannot handle LFs.  It *can* handle them, but only when it's writing them.  Not when reading them.

So, I couldn't completely do the job with sed, as I hoped.  I like sed's in-place switch, which seems less messy than creating another file and thus appeals to my OCD.

The format of my file was :

```
Mary(LF)
Smith(LF)
(SUB)(LF)
John(LF)
Public(LF)
(SUB)(LF)
```

and I wanted a result of:

```
Mary(TAB)Smith(LF)
John(TAB)Public(LF)
```

So, I wanted to change LF to TAB, and LF-SUB-LF to LF.

I solved my problem by first using TR to change all LFs to TABs. Couldn't use sed for this.

```
# change LFs to TABs ... so grep can later treat entire file as one line
tr '\012' '\011' < comengo.extract.txt > comengo.extract.out
mv comengo.extract.out comengo.extract.txt
```

That way, sed can now treat the entire file as one line.  sed only likes to treat files line-by-line, so I made the whole fine one single line.

The second step was to let sed jump in, and make the changes I wanted.  The gist of my question was "how do I represent non-printing ascii characters?".

My previous attempts were failing because I was trying to use \x12 in the sed search string.  Now that the LFs were replaced, I used an uninterrupted sequence of hex numbers.

```
# changes (tab)(sub)(tab) to just (sub)
sed -i 's/\x09\x1A\x09/\x1A/g'   comengo.extract.tx
```

Then I restored LFs to the file by using sed, which can write LFs

```
# (sub) to (tab)(lf)
sed -i 's/\x1A/\x0A\x09/g'  comengo.extract.txt
```

And that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `tr`?

```
tr '\012' '\011' < myfile.txt > tmp.out
mv tmp.out myfile.txt
```

The `tr` command is a pure filter; it does not (in the standard versions, at any rate) take any file name arguments or support overwriting or ...

Comment: Thanks, but TR cannot do replacement in-place.  Is what I seek not really possible with cygwin sed?

Comment: I dunno; I would use `tr` and not worry.  Since you're flattening the file by removing newlines, I'd be worried about using `sed` which is line-oriented.  Why is it crucial it is done 'in place'?  Are you sure the way `sed` does 'in place' makes enough difference?

Comment: I'm not just trying to get a fish.  I am trying to learn fishing.  In other words, I am trying to learn sed.  My plans call for the work to be done in-place.  Can sed search & replace one unprintable ascii character with another?

Comment: 'Tis good to learn to fish — you are to be commended.  `sed` is an editor that reads and processes lines.  If you replace newlines with tabs, you are messing with the way `sed` works.  If you were trying to replace 0xA0 (non-breaking blank) with 0x20 (blank), then you'd be able to use `sed` for the job.  Were you changing ESC (escape, 0x1B) with SOH (control-A, 0x01), then you'd be able to use `sed` for the job.  If you are changing newline to tab, I'm not convinced `sed` is the tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

The portable way to specify a linefeed in sed is with an escaped return:

```
sed -i 's/\
/<tab>/g'
```

Replace the text `<tab>` with a literal tab character.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` or `ksh` I'd suggest you use the shell's `$'...'` syntax which support C style backslash escapes. For example:

```
[BASH] # echo $'hello\nworld'
hello
world
[BASH] # echo $'hello\x0aworld'
hello
world
[BASH] #
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact sed can match LF characters, if you use --null-data on top of --binary:

`$ echo -e "Line1\r\nLine2\rLine3\nLine4\n\rLine5" | sed --null-data --binary -r -e "s/\x0d\x0a/\x0a/g" | od --format=x1a
0000000  4c  69  6e  65  31  0a  4c  69  6e  65  32  0d  4c  69  6e  65
          L   i   n   e   1  nl   L   i   n   e   2  cr   L   i   n   e
0000020  33  0a  4c  69  6e  65  34  0a  0d  4c  69  6e  65  35  0a
          3  nl   L   i   n   e   4  nl  cr   L   i   n   e   5  nl`